# How can I place below this slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I have this slideshow that no matter what I do stays out of the flow and every new element I add doesn't see it and gets placed above it. I need my footer to be below the slideshow. I tried wrapping it in a div with a relative position but it doesn't work. The jsfiddle provided is the exact code I have, except my slideshow is smaller and is in the middle of the screen. https://jsfiddle.net/87axbx1o/

````
  display: flex; 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
}

#img1{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: xfade 15s -0s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


#img2{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: xfade 15s -5s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}


#img3{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: xfade 15s -10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes xfade{

     0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}```
````

Comment: Please post a working [repro] for debugging details. A fiddle is onyl allowed as extension but does not replace the StackSnippet. Question must be self-containg without relaying on external resources.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the position of the images is `absolute`. Use a wrapper like you've tried, set its position to `relative`, its width and height, and it should work.

```css
.slideshow-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}
.imgbox{
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover; 
}

#img1{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: xfade 15s -0s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#img2{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: xfade 15s -5s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#img3{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: xfade 15s -10s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes xfade{

     0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
.header,
.footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p>
  Header
  </p>
</div>
<div class="slideshow-wrapper">
  <div id="img1" class="imgbox" style="background-image: url('http://img2.netcarshow.com/Ford-GT90_Concept_1995_800x600_wallpaper_01.jpg');">
  </div>

  <div id="img2" class="imgbox" style="background-image: url('http://img2.netcarshow.com/Mercedes-Benz-SLR_McLaren_2004_800x600_wallpaper_02.jpg');">
  </div>

  <div id="img3" class="imgbox" style="background-image: url('http://img2.netcarshow.com/Porsche-911_Carrera_4S_2002_800x600_wallpaper_0d.jpg');">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <p>
  Footer
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. However it still doesn't work because I have img tags inserted between each div. With your code it doesn't work either, only if images are inserted using style="background-image". As you soon as you remove that and add images using the img tag they start behaving like absolute elements again.

Comment: Well, it works with the code you provided. Why would you provide a different code than what you actually use?

Comment: My apologies, i forgot to include my own HTML code. Could you possibly take another look at this? My divs look like this <div id="img2" class="imgbox">
        <img src='review22.jpg'>
      </div>

Comment: Just specify the dimensions of the `img` and you'll be fine. Add `.imgbox img { width:100%; height: 100%; }`. Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cm308qz7/

Comment: Thank you, I figured that out by accident yesterday :)